# Alerts & Reminders based on SMS content

Tags: sms, notifications, motorola-atrix-4g

At work I get paged by our automated system. The problem is that the numbers come across unique each time. 1(999)000-0001, 1(999)000-0002, etc.

The body of the SMS is the same each time tho, in the form of an email:

```
FRM: helpdesk@mycompany.com
SUBJ:(12345)Company pager
This is a Page from the Pager
```

Since the number changes each time, is their a "notification" app that can say "If the SMS starts with 'FRM: helpdesk@mycompany.com', ignore silence mode and use this ringtone".

I'm using reminder programs that let me know if I've missed a message... but I want to differentiate the SMS's from the ancient paging program we use.

Comment: GoSMS has a filter feature that supposedly moves messages based either on content within the message body OR if the number is unknown - to a separate area called FILTER BOX. I've not tried it myself, but see if custom ringtones can be assigned to FILTER BOX messsages - that would solve your requirement, perhaps.

Comment: I see the custom filter box... haven't had a chance to dig in and see if ring-tones can be assigned. GoSMS has a lot of features to dig through.

Comment: UPDATE: https://market.android.com/details?id=net.nousefor.smsfilter has the ability to look thru the body of the message and display a notification. Not freeware, but check it out, nonetheless.

Comment: Certainly there must be a way, as the Prey app uses the content of an SMS message to turn itself on or off. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) for this. *Tasker* can react on a lot of events, an incoming SMS being only one of the many. You can then have it parse the SMS text, and react on keywords. There're probably already som "profiles" out in the wild which you could adapt (just check with a [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=tasker+profile+sms)), you also can find more details on [SMS Notification Management - Tasker Wiki](http://tasker.wikidot.com/sms-notification-management). This is probably the most flexible solution.

To sum up alternatives already mentioned in the comments:

- [GO SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) offers a filter feature, as Sparx mentioned
- [SMS-Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nousefor.smsfilter) can check the SMS body and display notifications (again from Sparx)